# rails devise confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation-email

I am using devise for authentication & able to send confirmation email.
I want to know is there any configuration available to expire confirmation link in email after certain duration?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable - the configuration option you're looking for is `confirm_within`.
The confirmation token should be generated before the user record is created, that is if the model includes the `:confirmable` option.

Comment: confirm_within specifies duration for which user is allowed to access site without confirming.. it does not expire link..

Comment: `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` does that. `confirm_within` should do what you need.

Comment: i tried again but confirm_within is not working in manner you suggested. link is not expiring in duraion i have specified..fyi i am using rails 2.3.15 & devise 1.0.11

Comment: In this case you were correct - for that devise version, `confirm_within` doesn't do what you want. Unless you can upgrade to a newer version, you're stuck.